# Getting expected unqualified-id error with C++ when trying to complie

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment for class and keep getting an "expected unqualified-id" for the "{" after defining my bool types in the function. I can't figure out why I'm getting this error and it is making it hard to get my assignment done without being able to run my program. Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error? Here is my code

```
//Page 825 Problem 12

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


//Function Prototype
bool testPassword(char []);

const int passLength = 21;
char password[passLength];

int main()
{
//Ask user to enter password matching the following criteria
cout << "Please enter a password at six characters long. \n"
<< "Password must also contain at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter. \n"
<< "Password must also contain at least one digit. \n"
<< "Please enter your password now \n";

cin.getline (password, passLength);

if (testPassword(password))
    cout << "Password entered is of the correct format and has been accepted.";

else
    cout << "Password does not meet criteria \n";


return 0;
}

//*******************************
//**Function to test password ***
//**to determine if it meets  ***
//**criteria listed           ***
//*******************************

//Test password to determine if it is at least six characters long
bool testPassword (char password[]);


bool lower;
bool upper;
bool digit;
bool length;

 {

    if (strlen(password) < 6)
        length = true;

    else
        length = false;
        cout << "Password must be at least 6 characters long.\n";


for (int k = 0; k < passLength; k++)
{
    if (islower(password[k])
        lower = true;
    else
        lower = false;
        cout << "Password must contain a lowercase letter.\n";


    if (isupper(password[k])
        upper = true;
    else
        upper = false;
        cout << "Password must contain an uppercase letter.\n";


    if (isdigit(password[k])
        digit = true;

    else
        digit = false;
        cout << "Password must contain a digit.\n";

}
if (lower && upper && digit && length == true)

        return true;

    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Post your actual code and error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

testPassword: has a ";" and the end of line that it shouldn't have.

The bool variables need to be inside the first "{", not before it.

Comment: Thanks guys, its always the simple stuff that I seem to miss =/ ... I really appreciate the quick help =)

Comment: n.p.

Please hit the Up or Accept button on the answer if it answers you question.

Comment: @Mageneto: Please note the second problem: you need braces for your if/else statement, too.  It will compile OK ... but it won't behave as you expect.  See my response for details.

Answer (score 0):

This part is placed within global scope:

```
bool testPassword (char password[]);   // <-- declaration of function
bool lower;                            // <-- global variables
bool upper;
bool digit;
bool length;
{               // <-- start of the scope? what does it belong to?
    ...
```

and it is invalid, you can not place program's logic in global scope... functions can not be just called "out of nowhere"... if it was supposed to be the body of `testPassword` function already, it should be:

```
bool testPassword (char password[])
{
    bool lower;
    bool upper;
    bool digit;
    bool length;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you actually want this:

```
bool testPassword (char password[])
{
   bool lower;
   bool upper;
   bool digit;
   bool length;

if (strlen(password) < 6) {
    length = true;
}
else {
    length = false;
    cout << "Password must be at least 6 characters long.\n";
}
...
```

NOTES:

1. "testPassword()" with a ";" is a FUNCTION PROTOTYPE (not an actual function definition)
2. Unlike Python, just indenting doesn't make a conditional block.  If you want more than one line in the block, you need curly braces.